# How to register javax.jws.Webservice on Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, jax-ws, apache-camel, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot and my Application.java looks like this:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.servlet.CamelHttpTransportServlet;
import org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext;

@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    private static final String CAMEL_URL_MAPPING = "/camel/*";
    private static final String CAMEL_SERVLET_NAME = "CamelServlet";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean camelServletRegistration() {
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new CamelHttpTransportServlet(), CAMEL_URL_MAPPING);
        registration.setName(CAMEL_SERVLET_NAME);
        return registration;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringCamelContext camelContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws Exception {
        SpringCamelContext camelContext = new SpringCamelContext(applicationContext);
        camelContext.addRoutes(routeBuilder());
        return camelContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public RouteBuilder routeBuilder() {
        return new MyRouteBuilder();
    }
}
```

RouteBuilder.java is defined as follows:

```
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        // Access us using http://localhost:8080/camel/hello
        from("servlet:///hello").transform().constant("Hello from Camel!");

        // Trigger run right after startup. No Servlet request required.
        from("timer://foo?fixedRate=true&period=10s").log("Camel timer triggered.");
    }
}
```

Everything works fine - Camel context is started and I can see "Hello from Camel!" message. Now I would like Camel to bind to WS instead of just simple Servlet.

I defined following WebService:

```
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;

@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://ws.mycompany.com/notification", name = "StatusNotificationService")
@XmlSeeAlso({ObjectFactory.class})
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
public class StatusNotificationServiceWS implements StatusNotificationServicePortType {

    @Override
    public void notify(@WebParam(partName = "parameter", name = "NotifyStatus", targetNamespace = "http://ws.mycompany.com/notification") NotifyStatus parameter) {
        throw new RuntimeException("This method should not be called!");
    }
}
```

How to register it using ServletRegistrationBean and refer to it using Apache Camel routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to publish the service, you can use [CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/servlet-transport.html) to do the job. 
But if you want to route the request to camel route, you need to use [camel-cxf](http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html) to setup CxfEndpoint

Answer (score 1):

Just to summarize:

I used camel-cxf by adding the following dependency to pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
  <version>${camel.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you can register camel cxf endpoint:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
       xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd">

    <cxf:cxfEndpoint id="notificationsWS" address="localhost:8080/notificationsWS" serviceClass="org.company.StatusNotificationServiceWS">
    </cxf:cxfEndpoint>
</beans>
```

and create camel route based on the registered cxf-endpoint:

```
from("cxf:bean:notificationsWS?dataFormat=PAYLOAD").wireTap("direct:myRouter")
```